# Retention Policies for OneDrive and SharePoint Onlie - Licensing Requirements

Tags: sharepoint-online, office-365, licensing, retention

We have a tenant with the **Microsoft 365 Business Premium** subscription. Having this license, are we allowed to setup the retention policies for SharePoint Online?

When I go to the Compliance Center > Policies, I don't see the "**Retention**" link. Is it because **Microsoft 365 Business Premium** does not include **retention** policies?

[image]

**Update**

I have checked a different tenant with the **Microsoft 365 Business Essentials** subscription. And I can see the **Retention** option available:

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out even the cheapest Microsoft 365 business license has the **Retentions** options in the compliance center. If it does not show up, it simply means that the license is not assigned to the account that needs this feature.

When we assigned the license to the service account we were using, the **Retention** option showed up.

Comment: Hi, Denis Molodtsov. Thanks for your sharing. Have a nice day!

Answer (score 0):

Based on my research, **M365 Business Premium** only supports the Retention policy of Exchange Online. For the Retention policy of SharePoint\OneDrive, you need E3+ or SharePoint Online P2. For the Teams, you need E3+.

**More information, please see the following articles:**

- **[Microsoft 365 licensing guidance for security & compliance](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/office365/servicedescriptions/microsoft-365-service-descriptions/microsoft-365-tenantlevel-services-licensing-guidance/microsoft-365-security-compliance-licensing-guidance#information-governance)**
- **[Set up compliance features](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-365/business/set-up-compliance?view=o365-worldwide)**

Comment: Stange, but in the tenant with a cheaper license type, I can see the retention option. My busienss essentials, for example, has this option visible.

Comment: Hi, Denis Molodtsov. Based on my research, M365 Business Premium only supports the Retention policy of Exchange Online.